# Compile Ant project with two jdk versions

Tags: java-8, gwt, ant, java-11

I am working on Ant project. I am using GWT for client side. Means both client side and Server-side code is written in java. But now we have to upgrade jdk version from jdk-1.8 to jdk-11 for hibernate upgradation. But jdk-11 does not support GWT or we don't want to upgrade GWT.

Now I have to compile and build client-side code with jdk-1.8 and server-side code with jdk-11 with single command i.e. "ant war.all".
Is it possible? if yes then What will be the procedure for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below method to build both server- and client-side code with JAVA 8 while having default JDK set to JAVA 11. I'm not sure if it would work when compilation of server- and client-side code use different JDKs - give it a try.

---

In Ant `build.xml` you have `javac` command to compile java source to bytecode. This is the server side.

The [`javac` command](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) has `fork` and `executable` parameters which can be used to set the path to the external javac executable.

> fork: Whether to execute javac using the JDK compiler externally.

> executable: Complete path to the javac executable to use in case of fork is yes.

```
<javac
       fork="yes"
       executable="/path/to/javac"
       ...
```

---

For the client side the [`java` command](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) is used to execute GWT compiler. The `java` command also has a `fork` parameter that triggers the class execution in another JVM (other than the one Ant is currently using), and a `jvm` parameter - the command used to invoke JVM.

```
<java
      fork="true"
      jvm="/path/to/java"
      ...
```